# Permutations - selection

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Give the total number of possible arrangements of 3 letters chosen from the word CALCULUS.  The answer is 96, but all I can get is 5P3=60 (permutations of 3 from 5 different elements), or 8P3 adjusted for three pairs of identical elements, i.e. 8!/(2!2!2!5!)=42.

I would really appreciate the workings.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to make cases like selecting all distinct alphabets or taking 2 same et cetera...

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you may not use any letter more times then present in CCLLUUAS, you arrangement either contains $3$ distinct letters or two equal letters and a third distinct letter (there are no letters present three times). In the former case you have $\binom53=10$ choices to the subset of letters and $6$ permutations of the letter, for $60$ possibilities. In the latter case you have $3$ choices for the doubled letter, $4$ choices for the remaining letter, and $3$ distinct permutations, for $36$ possibilities. In total $60+36=96$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the following:  All three letter strings can be broken into the following *disjoint* types (disjoint meaning that they don't overlap)

Type 1: There are no repeated letters (all letters are different, for example CAL)

Type 2: There is a letter repeated once (there are two types of letters, one of which appears twice, for example ACC)

Type 3: There is a letter repeated twice (there is a single type of letter, appearing 3 times, for example GGG)

The number of type1 3 letter words are as you got $~_5P_3 = 5\cdot 4\cdot 3=60$

The number of type2 3letter words can be found by multiplication principle: Pick the location of the nonrepeated letter (either first second or third slot), pick the repeated letter (either C,L, or U), pick the nonrepeated letter (something other than what was picked in step2 or A or S) to get $3\cdot 3\cdot 4 = 36$

There are no type3 3 letter words in this case, since there are no letters that appear three times in calculus.  $0$

By inclusion-exclusion, or by addition principle (or whatever you want to call it), you may add the number of possibilities from *disjoint* sets (like these) to get a final total of $60+36+0=96$

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to choose a $3$ **unique** letter word from CALCULUS is $10$:

- It is equal to the number of ways to choose $3$ letters from CALUS: $\binom53=10$

The number of ways to choose a $3$ **non-unique** letter word from CALCULUS is $12$:

- CCA, CCL, CCS, CCU
- LLA, LLC, LLS, LLU
- UUA, UUC, CCL, CCS

Each **unique** letter word has $3!=6$ different arrangements.

Each **non-unique** letter word has $\binom32=3$ different arrangements.

So the total number of $3$ letter arrangements is $10\cdot6+12\cdot3=96$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with generating functions.  You'll want to use exponential generating functions, since the order of the letters matters.  There are 3 letters you're allowed to use up to twice, and two letters you can only use once, so the number of 3-letter words you can form is the coefficient of $x^3/3!$ in
$$(1+x+x^2/2!)^3\,(1+x)^2.$$

The coefficient of $x^3$ is $16$; multiplying by $3!$ gives $96$.